# Error in writing a matrix in a for loop to a file

Tags: python

I have to write matrix of n*m size to a file. Error is a file is created but output of matrix is not saved  to the file. Kindly help me in rectifying error. Here is the code.

```
# m1 is a matrix having n*m rows
f = open("ouput.txt", "w")
for r in range(0,n):
   for c in range(0,n):
       m1=[m1[i,j],m2[i,j+1]],[m1[i+1,j],m1[i+1,j+1]] 
       for i in range(2):
           for j in range(2):
              f.write[m1]
```

Comment: For starters, I think you need `for c in range(0,m):` not `... in range(0,n)`. Secondly, the rest of your code will likely encounter `NameError`s because it references `i` and `j` before they're defined (and `m2` appears to be undefined). You need to use `r` and `c` to select (index) which element of the matrix you want to output.

Answer (score 0):

As martineau said, you are attempting to reference i,j, and m2 before they are defined. Additionally, if m1 is a matrix, for example:

```
m1 = [[0,1,2],
      [2,3,4],
      [5,3,8]]
```

and you want to access 3 in m1 then it would be `m1[1][1]` not `m[1,1]`

I'm assuming this was your reasoning for doing:

`m1=[m1[i,j],m2[i,j+1]],[m1[i+1,j],m1[i+1,j+1]]`

and `f.write[m1]` will also produce a `TypeError`

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116460/error-in-writing-a-matrix-in-a-for-loop-to-a-file?answertab=votes#tab-top) Thankyou